# Braintree subscription for recurring payments

Tags: php, payment, braintree

Let a customer has subscribed for a product for $10 monthly and his starting date is 11-May-2011 which ends on 10-June-2011, So my question was that after expiry of subscription on 11-June-2011 who will charge for recurring payment from customer. Braintree will charge the customer or we (merchant) have to send a request for that to Braintree.

If merchant have to charge then what is the process and it would be great if someone provides PHP code sample.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can set up a subscription in Braintree which will charge your customers monthly. You need to set up the subscription plan manually (such as $10 per month) in your braintree admin control panel, but you use the API to sign up customers to the subscription plan you created, and do not need to have your app remind braintree to bill each month.

The Braintree API docs to setup subscriptions in PHP are at the following link:
http://www.braintreepayments.com/docs/php/subscriptions/overview

Comment: I have a situation, where in i am passing the price for a particular plan dynamically from my code.At the time of subscription renewal, would braintree use the default plan's price(the default price configured from the braintree controll panel), or would it use the one which i passed dynamically by invoking the api. In my case i want braintree to use the price which i passed dynamically via api..
In the documentation it is written that the dynamically passed price will be used. but would it be used for subscription renewal as well. does anybody have any clue how can i verify it.